# spring integration sftp autowire outbound channel adapter to reuse remote file name/remote directory

Tags: spring-integration-sftp

I need to transfer file to a remote server. I use the spring integration sftp package.

I define the outbound-channel-adapter in an xml file, where I define what is the remote file name, and what is the remote directory

```
    <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="inputChannel"
            remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName() + '_foo'"
            remote-directory="/var/tmp/cctng-transfer">
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

The transfer works well, however I would like to setup group ownership for the file.
so, I would like to know in my class the settings I put in the xml already instead of hard coding again.

in another method, after file transfer I call that, like:

```
setOwnerGroup(fileName + "_foo");


private void setOwnerGroup(String fileName) {
    RemoteFileTemplate<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> template = new RemoteFileTemplate<>(sessionFactory);
    template.execute(session -> {
        ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.getClientInstance();
        try {
            channel.chgrp(26, "/var/tmp/cctng-transfer/" + fileName);
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```